# How do I flip a bar chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2016

In excel, I have a set of percentages and a set of text labels.  When I create a bar graph going horizontally, I see "label 5" at the top and "label 1" at the bottom.  There doesn't seem to be a way to flip the chart.  What am I missing here?

| label 1 | 10% |
| label 2 | 30% |
| label 3 | 20% |
| label 4 | 55% |
| label 5 | 12% |

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/hub/excelling-at-excel-how-to-quickly-flip-a-chart

Comment: If that answers your problem, please let me know and I'll be happy to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Format tab.
Excel chart tools - Select the Format tab
Go to the Chart Elements drop down list and pick Vertical (Value) Axis.
Excel charts -  Vertical(value) Axis
Click the Format Selection button to see the Format Axis window
On the Format Axis window tick the Values in reverse order checkbox.
Tick the Values in reverse order checkbox on this window

Comment: **This was the answer from the link I posted in a comment.**